# How to click on button having no identifier in pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

In pywinauto32 how i can access button inside pan having no identifier

Button without any identifier:
[image]

Print identifier:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way except hard coded relative coordinates like this:

```
app.MainFormName.FilterDefinitionTemp.pane.click_input(coords=(20, 5), absolute=False)
```

Comment: Thanks @vasily Ryabov ,I tried this solution but it does't work on different screen size so basically this is the issue. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Another way is to get `.rectangle()` and its `.width()` and `.height()` to calculate target point as a proportion of whole grid size.

Comment: Thanks Vasily Ryabov for your guidance.